# Lightning auraif render issue

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-if

I am having a complex application where I have 10 child component in a master component that is inside an application.

I am passing complex type from master component to all the 10 components.

This works but when I try to introduce an auraif to hide/show/render child components the aura application hangs on load.

Parent app:

```
<aura:application ...
    <c:masterComp />
</aura:application>
```

Master Comp:

```
<aura:attribute name="complexWrpObj" type="ComplexWrapperClass" />

<c:child1 complexWrpObj="{!v.complexWrpObj}" />
<c:child2 complexWrpObj="{!v.complexWrpObj}" />
<c:child3 complexWrpObj="{!v.complexWrpObj}" />
...
</aura:component>
```

Master Comp JS:

```
({
doInit: function(cmp) {
    var action = cmp.get("c.severValue");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            cmp.set("v.complexWrpObj", response.getReturnValue());

        }
        else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {

        }
        else if (state === "ERROR") {

        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
})
```

Class:

```
public class ComplexWrapperClass{

@AuraEnabled Map<String,Account> wrpMap {get;set;}
@AuraEnabled Map<String,boolean> showHideMap {get;set;}
@AuraEnabled Map<String,String> etc {get;set;}

public ComplexWrapperClass(){
showHide = Map<String,boolean>{'child1' : true, 'child2' : false ...};
}
}
```

Now when I do this, the page stops loading, goes stuck and hangs altogether.

```
<aura:If isTrue="{!v.complexWrpObj.showHideMap.child1}">
<c:child1 complexWrpObj="{!v.complexWrpObj}" />
</aura:If>
<c:child2 complexWrpObj="{!v.complexWrpObj}" />
<c:child3 complexWrpObj="{!v.complexWrpObj}" />
```

Not sure what am I doing wrong.

Also a side question, will passing objects in attributes to child have performance impact, also does not rending will help in performance improvement.

Comment: I'd recommend that you refactor things to implement some kind of event handlers. That appears to be what's at the root of your issues. It seems you need to be passing local events and notifications between your components (define some attributes to support them) and either set them or think in terms of bubbling if possible so they will be more loosely coupled.